# Configuration is still incorrect. Do you want to edit it again? in android studio while running app

Tags: android, android-studio

While running my android app it shows the above error. I tried to change AVD manager "Use Host GPU" but  could not found that. Android emulator opened but still it showing black screen and Not even show that android words. I am using Mac OS.

Answer (score 10):

First of all, check the window "Edit Configuration" that opens when you click in "Run" or "Debug" button.
Then, check the bottom section "Before launch: Gradle-aware Make". Click on that small triangle to hide it. An error message should appear. This message should give you a clue about your problem.
In my case this message says: "Error: Default Activity not found", that's because I was changed my 
`<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

for

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`

Hope this help you or somebody. Sorry for the english.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Start Android Studio. Go to:

   - Windows and Linux: File/Settings.
   - Mac OS X: Android Studio/Preferences.
2. Select Plugins and click Browse repositories.
3. Right-click (double-click for Mac OS X) on Genymotion.
4. Click Download and install and proceed with the next steps.
5. Restart Android Studio by clicking Restart.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this update. In my case, the package name was not the correct one. I had copied a MainActivity from another app and not changed the package name.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, setting the `MainActivity.kt` as default was not my issue, but SDK version was creating the problem. So just check that and sync gradle on app level.